# React state is overwritten to empty in componentDidUpdate after it was set to a value

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am writing a signup component and setting an error in `componentDidUpdate` based on the response from the server using Redux but on submit the state is later set to empty after some seconds i.e immediately after the error message was set to the state, it was set to empty again.

```
state = {
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
    password: ""
    msg: null,   
};  

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { error } = this.props;

    if (error !== prevProps.error) {
        // check for register error
        if (error.id === "REGISTER_FAIL") {
            this.setState({ msg: error.msg.message });
        } else {
            this.setState({ msg: "null" });
        }
    }
}

render() {
    console.log(this.state)
}
```

I expect to get the error message in `this.state.msg` but instead, I get an empty `this.state.msg` while the error exists in the error props.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best place to handle such situations and avoid re-render/infinite loops is to handle it in [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) method of `react` life cycle.

```
state = {
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
    password: ""
    msg: null,
    prevPropMsg: null // we don't need this state, we can re-use msg state if you are not mutating msg state apart from in getDerivedStateFromProps method
};  

static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if (nextProps.error !== prevState.prevPropMsg) {
        // check for register error
        if (nextProps.error.id === "REGISTER_FAIL") {
            return { 
               msg: nextProps.error.msg.message,
               prevPropMsg: nextProps.error.msg.message
            };
        } else {
            return { 
               msg: null,
               prevPropMsg: null
            };
        }
    }

    return null;
}

render() {
    console.log(this.state)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your component will immediately re-render when you call `setState` from `componentDidUpdate`. This would be ok if you did not call `setState` in your `else` condition. What I believe is happening is you are setting the error, your component re-renders, and your `else` condition resets the message. Verify this by checking the output of:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) { 
  const { error } = this.props;
  if (error !== prevProps.error) {
    // check for register error
    if (error.id === "REGISTER_FAIL") {
      this.setState({ msg: error.msg.message });
      console.log('if');
    } else {
      this.setState({ msg: null });
      console.log('else');
    }
  }
}
```

if both are firing. That will confirm your problem.

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate):

> You may call setState() immediately in componentDidUpdate() but note that it must be wrapped in a condition like in the example above, or you’ll cause an infinite loop. It would also cause an extra re-rendering which, while not visible to the user, can affect the component performance. If you’re trying to “mirror” some state to a prop coming from above, consider using the prop directly instead. Read more about [why copying props into state causes bugs](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html).